# How to use custom fonts in my game? (License question)

Tags: licensing, game-development

I would like to use Roboto font in my libGDX game, but it's licensed under Apache license 2.0. Do I have to include the font license file in my game if I want to use it? I am using internal storage (assets folder), so the file probably would not be visible anyways without reverse-engineering the game.

Comment: If you just distribute a binary, read Section 4 point a (and possibly point d). That's what you have to do to comply with redistribution -  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Comment: An easy way would be to include a NOTICES file (like point d) and then you can state that portions of your work are copyright by Roboto-font-author's name and state the license under which that subwork is granted (a copy of the Apache License)